# How to add dates with dataset that have a start and end date?

Tags: postgresql, date, range

Hello I am a beginner at SQL, especially postgresql. 
I have a table that looks something like this:

```
ID    | Entity   | Startdate | enddate
------| ------   | ------    | ------ 
1     | Hospital |2013-01-01 |2013-01-31
1     | Clinic   |2013-02-01 |2013-04-30
1     | Hospital |2013-05-01 |2013-05-31
```

What I would like to do in this case is that where the start and end date span more than a month to break it out so the above table would like this:

```
ID    | Entity   | Startdate | enddate
------| ------   | ------    | ------
1     | Hospital |2013-01-01 |2013-01-31
1     | Clinic   |2013-02-01 |2013-02-29
1     | Clinic   |2013-03-01 |2013-03-31
1     | Clinic   |2013-04-01 |2013-04-30
1     | Hospital |2013-05-01 |2013-05-31
```

If you notice that row 2, 3 and 4 have been broken down by the month and the ID and entity have also been duplicated.

Any suggestions on how to run this in postgresql would be appreciated.

P.S Apologies I am trying to figure out how to create the table above properly. Having difficulty, the pipes between the numbers and words are lines in a table. 
Hope its not too confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to create yourself an end_of_month function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION end_of_month(date)
  RETURNS date AS
$BODY$
select (date_trunc('month', $1) + interval '1 month' - interval '1 day')::date;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT
  COST 100;
```

Then you can have a string of UNIONS like this:

```
SELECT 
        id, 
        entity, 
        startdate, 
        least(end_of_month(startdate),enddate) enddate 
from hospital
union
SELECT 
        id, 
        entity, 
        startdate, 
        least(end_of_month((startdate + interval '1 month')::date),enddate) enddate 
        from hospital
union
        id, 
        entity, 
        startdate, 
        least(end_of_month((startdate + interval '1 month')::date),enddate) enddate 
        from hospital
ORDER BY startdate,enddate
```

The problem with this approach, is that you need to have as many unions as necessary!

The alternative is to use a cursor.

EDIT

Just thought of another (better) non-cursor solution.  Create a table of month-end dates.  Then you can simply do:

```
select h.id, 
       h.entity, 
       h.startdate, 
       least(h.enddate, m.enddate) enddate
from hospital h 
INNER JOIN monthends m 
ON m.enddate > h.startdate and m.enddate <= end_of_month(h.enddate) 
ORDER BY startdate, enddate
```

Comment: monthends could be a CTE made using generate_series.

Comment: @Jasen Yes you could do that.  Thanks for the suggestion.  In the end it is a trade off really between use of permanent table and speed of execution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example how to clone row based on its data:

```
-- Demo data begin
with t(i,x,y) as (values
  (1, '2013-02-03'::date, '2013-04-27'::date),
  (2, current_date, current_date))
-- Demo data end
select
  *,
  greatest(x, z)::date as x1, least(y, z + '1 month - 1 day'::interval)::date as y1
from
  t,
  generate_series(date_trunc('month', x)::date, date_trunc('month', y)::date, '1 month') as z;
```

```
┌───┬────────────┬────────────┬────────────────────────┬────────────┬────────────┐
│ i │     x      │     y      │           z            │     x1     │     y1     │
╞═══╪════════════╪════════════╪════════════════════════╪════════════╪════════════╡
│ 1 │ 2013-02-03 │ 2013-04-27 │ 2013-02-01 00:00:00+02 │ 2013-02-03 │ 2013-02-28 │
│ 1 │ 2013-02-03 │ 2013-04-27 │ 2013-03-01 00:00:00+02 │ 2013-03-01 │ 2013-03-31 │
│ 1 │ 2013-02-03 │ 2013-04-27 │ 2013-04-01 00:00:00+03 │ 2013-04-01 │ 2013-04-27 │
│ 2 │ 2017-08-27 │ 2017-08-27 │ 2017-08-01 00:00:00+03 │ 2017-08-27 │ 2017-08-27 │
└───┴────────────┴────────────┴────────────────────────┴────────────┴────────────┘
```

Just remove `Demo data` block and replace `t`, `x` and `y` by your table/columns names.

Explanation:

`least()` and `greatest()` function returns minimum and maximum element accordingly. [Link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-GREATEST-LEAST)

`generate_series(v1,v2,d)` function returns series of values started with `v1`, not greatest then `v2` with step `d`. [Link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html#FUNCTIONS-SRF-SERIES)

`'1 month - 1 day'::interval` - `interval` data type notation, `<value>::<datatype>` means explicit type casting, the SQL standard equivalent is `cast(<value> as <datatype>)`. [Link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html) and [link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/typeconv.html)

`date_trunc()` function truncates the date/timestamp value to the specified precision. [Link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html)